# The fastest filling one pixel in JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I use canvas in JavaFX library. I need to draw many pixels as fast as possible. I execute this :

```
canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(color);
canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

I suppose it is very slow. Can I use faster way? Maybe should I use another way/method to fill one pixel?

Comment: Are you only drawing pixels on the canvas or are you using other canvas APIs as well?

Comment: I use default canvas : `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas`

Comment: I know you use a canvas, but I'm trying to work out if you should.  If all you are doing is manipulating pixels, you don't need a canvas, a WritableImage would be enough and would likely perform better.  If you are doing other things such as drawing lines on the canvas, then you need a canvas.

Comment: I implement algorithms such as: z-buffer, phong shading etc. which can convert my 3D objects to the 2D image.

Comment: See this thread on [canvas performance](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712).  Using the PixelWriter for an Image with a plain ImageView is probably best for your case.  If I get some time, I'll post an answer, but in the meantime anybody can put together an answer based on the comments and linked thread.  For canvas you are looking for [graphicsContext.getPixelWriter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#getPixelWriter--)

Comment: [JavaFX has built-in 3D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm), but I guess the built-in implementation doesn't fit your need.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the PixelWriter from an Image.
As @jewelsea said use [canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#getPixelWriter--)

With the PixelWriter you can paint any Pixel you want:

[pixelWriter.setColor(int x, int y,Color c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html#setColor-int-int-javafx.scene.paint.Color-)

I think this is the best way for only Paint pixels.

You can also waive the Canvas and use an ImageView with an WriteAbleImage in it.

In this case you can use 
[writableImage.getPixelWriter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html#getPixelWriter--)
in the same way as the Canvas.

If this is still to slow you can Execute the pixelWriter.setColor(..) in a background Thread so the Application don't stop.

See also:

[canvas performance](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712)

I hope this answer helps you.